# Tag for Victorian times?

Tags: feature-request

In regards to [my proposal for a Victorian SE on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82859/victorian), [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19675/couldnt-you-just-make-a-tag) came up.

I think it would indeed be a better idea to create a tag for this on the History SE, instead of having a SE for Victorian times on their own.

Seeing there are a few questions on this topic, is it something to maybe consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a [victorian](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/victorian) tag already. It only has 8 entries, but feel free to add more. The [19th-century](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/19th-century) tag however currently has more than 150 entries.

We'd certainly be happy to field your Victorian-era questions, as long as they fit within the bounds of history.

Then if the day comes that this is a thriving release (non-beta) stack and we are fielding 5+ questions a day on the Victorian-era, it may make sense to split that out into its own stack. We need to get the base history stack out of beta first though.